# Select Betweeen em data CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller

Estou tentando selecionar registros em um intervalo de datas.

```
$mesAtual = $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'compras', 'action' => 'comprasMes'), array('condicoes' => array('Compra.status' => array(1,2), 'Compra.data BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('06/30/2015', '07/30/2015')), 'ordem' => array('Compra.data_pagamento' => 'desc')));
```

O que acontece é que os registros tem retornado mas não consigo ordenar os dados: `'ordem' => array('Compra.data_pagamento' => 'desc')`.

Veja como está no controller

```
public function comprasMes(){
    $condicoes = $this->params->params['condicoes'];
    $ordem = isset($this->params->params['ordem']) ?: null;

    $compras = $this->Compra->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array($condicoes), $ordem ));

    return $compras;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que passar esses filtros no mesmo array

```
public function comprasMes(){
    $condicoes = array(
        'conditions' => $this->params->params['condicoes'],
        'order' => isset($this->params->params['ordem'])? $this->params->params['ordem'] : array(); 
    );

    $compras = $this->Compra->find('all', $condicoes);

    return $compras;
}
```

Comment: Valeu. Deu certo aqui!!